# Finding the maximum of sum of coefficients of a polynomial

Tags: inequality, polynomials, quadratics

Suppose $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is a quadratic polynomial with real coefficients and $|p(x)| \leq 1$ for all values of $x$ in the range $[0,1]$. Prove that maximum possible value of $|a|+|b|+|c|$ is $17$.

I could not even start the problem.
Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: $p= 8(x-1/2)^2 - 1= 8x^2-8x+1$ will achieve the bound $17.$

Comment: @abel can you please explain how you got that quadratic

Comment: it is more trial and error. you expect the maximum of the quadratic to be at the boundaries $x = 0, 1$ and too symmetric about $x = 1/2.$  i don't have a proof that this is the max.

Comment: May this problem be related to Chebyshev polynomials?

Comment: @uranix, i think so. in fact, i remember something about this todds textbook constructive analysis.

Comment: I don't think that would extend for larger powers, just like Chebyshev polynomials do

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$a=2f(1)+2f(0)-4f(\frac{1}{2}),b=4f(\dfrac{1}{2})-f(1)-3f(0)，c=f(0)$$
so
$$|a|le 2|f(1)|+4|f(\frac{1}{2})|+2|f(0)|=2+4+2=8$$
simaler
$|b|\le 8,|c|\le 1$.then we have
$$|a|+|b|+|c|\le 17$$